# jquery: manipulating divs and adding effects causes endless loop of uncaught TypeErrors

Tags: jquery, slidedown, dom-manipulation

I am trying to perform three tasks in sequence:

a) load html-content via ajax into a hidden div.

b) traverse the content and insert elements into existing divs.

c) add a `slideDown` animation to each newly appended div.

When I do this, I get an endless loop of errors

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object # is not a function

Here is the code:

```
for(var step=1;step<=total_steps;step++)
{
 add_target=$('#content');
 add_entry=$('#response_hidden').find('.slide :eq('+ step +')');

 add_entry.hide();
 add_entry.prependTo(add_target);
 add_entry.slideDown("slow");
}
```

Any clues?
Using this [ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js)

Comment: changed the jquery library to 1.7.2 and everything works fine... Any clue what changed?

Comment: gets stranger: using the Google CDN creates the error, downloading the script removes it. Now using V 1.9.1 on my own server.

Comment: I think the issue was occurring due multiple instance of Jquery running at your end..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 add_entry=$('#response_hidden').find('.slide:eq('+ step +')');
                                         -----^--- you have extra space here
```

Comment: did that - no change. BTW: Must have sthg to do with DOM not being ready upon prepending. If I do the same thing in the console, it works just fine.